# How to make discord bot check if a message was deleted by another bot

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I want to make my bot check for if a message was deleted by another bot then to send a message. I tried `message.author.bot` but that seems to check if the message was posted by a bot and not deleted by a bot. I am using discord.py rewrite if that means anything.

Comment: Does the bot in this case make a audit log when it deletes messages? If thats the case you could fetch the audit logs and use that! [AuditLogAction.message_delete](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=audit#discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete) (Edited, wasn't paying attention to the Lib you're using )

Comment: Hm, yeah I could try that. Thanks!